# Access networked machines processor/core information

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm trying to get information about the processors/cores of all networked machines. I've tried Environment.ProcessorCount and System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher but they seem to be limited to the machine im running the code from.

Is there a way to make these methods take the networked machines into account or alternatively  some methods that are a little more specific to networked machines info?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the assumption here that you're trying to work with the Windows OS and so the solution below will only work with Windows. Please clarify your question with this information if this is not correct.

You can use the WMI interface to access a huge amount of information from Windows-based machines remotely - *"WMI is intended to monitor the hardware and software on remote computers. Remote connections for WMI in .NET Framework are accomplished through the ManagementScope object."*

See the tutorial on how to do this in C# here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)